# Django ORM: how count in annotation differ from count on query set?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```py
qs = ...

qs = qs.annotate(v=Count('a', filter=Q(a__lt=5)))
a = qs.first().v
b = qs.filter(Q(a__lt=5)).count()

assert a == b  # error
```

Is there any reason why these methods could produce different results?

Comment: It looks like you *aggregate* in the first `qs`, not *annotate*.

Comment: What is field 'a', a FK?

Comment: it is just some non-zero field in the model

Comment: Then your first annotation doesn't make much sense, the annotation is always 1. Annotate is performed for each row.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my reasoning is that annotation will make aggregation count over entire qs and add the result to the every object inside qs. And the value of `v` should not be different from `filter().count()`, but for some reason it is.

Comment: annotation is per row. Count('a') is always 1.

Comment: @dirkgroten, it's not. In my case it is always 4, but `qs.count()` is 6000

Comment: that's not possible, it's always 1 if you're applying Count on an IntegerField of your model. Show us your model.

Comment: Anyway, annotations are on each row, they will never take into account other rows.

Comment: Your annotation can only have a value of 1 or 0, `a < 5` would be 1 otherwise it's zero. You should post the full query and model.

Comment: @bdoubleu no the filter doesn't work in this case, v is always 1 regardless of the value of 'a' when you count on a column of the row itself; I just tried it. Count with annotations only works with related models.

Comment: @dirkgroten, for some reason I still got 4 in the results. But you are right about count being calculated on each row. I need to reformulate my question for specific task

Comment: @dirkgroten which version of Django? I just tried with 2.2.4 the filter seems to be working because `v` is 0 or 1.

Comment: @bdoubleu oh, i'm on 1.11. didn't know this changed

Comment: @bdoubleu you're right, this works on Django 2.2 and was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#id8) about `Count(expression, **kwargs)`:

> Returns the number of objects that are related through the provided expression

So `Count` is specifically meant to count related objects (through FK or M2M relationships), and doesn't make much sense on any other column of the row itself. It'll usually return 1 in that case (might depend on your db what value is returned), since there's always 1 value.