# Django ORM: how to make aggregation with filter with annotated field?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have view with statistics where I calculate multiple `count`'s on different filters of some base query set:

```py
qs = Model.onjects.filter(...).annotate(a=...)
a = qs.filter(Q(a__lt=5)).count()
b = qs.filter(Q(a__lt=10)).count()  # this is just an example, real filters are more complex
...
```

But each count makes separate query to the DB and I want to optimize it. I tried `aggregation`:

```
qs.aggregate(
  a=Count('a', filter=Q(a__lt=5)), 
  b=Count('a', filter=Q(a__lt=10)),
)
```

but got an error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column '__col2' in 'field list'")`. I don't even know where this `__col2` comes from.

It seems like aggregation doesn't work well with annotation because when I use regular model field inside `count.filter` instead of annotated field `a` everything is fine.

Comment: Does the real filters, by any chance, contain a `__col2`, It might be better to look what is triggering the error, such that we can see *what* is causing errors.

Comment: is `aggregation` a typo? It's supposed to be `aggregate`

Comment: Just do `Count('pk', filter=Q(a__lt=5))`. It doesn't matter which column you count, but a calculated column might be an issue.

Comment: I guess what you want is kind of a "double" annotation. Something like: `qs.annotate(a=Count("a", filter=Q(a__lt=5)))`

Comment: @HigorRossato that won't work, as I explained in his previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063167/django-orm-how-count-in-annotation-differ-from-count-on-query-set)

Comment: @Aiven What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've done that on 2.2 and it worked. Wouldn't work because of Django version or something else?

Comment: @HigorRossato `annotate` works on each row, it won't count other rows. Not on any version of Django. OP wants the total count of all columns, so `aggregate` is the correct approach. But it depends on the version of Django whether the direct count he does works or not.

Comment: I see what you mean @dirkgroten. I misunderstood the question. So, ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Django 2.2, your approach should work, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation). You probably should count on `'pk'` as shown there, not sure you can count on the annotation itself:

```
qs.aggregate(
    a=Count('pk', filter(Q(a__lt=5)),
    b=Count('pk', filter(Q(a__lt=10))
)
```

If you're on Django 1.11, the above approach doesn't work as `Count` will always return 1, ignoring the filter. You should use `Case ... When`:

```
qs.aggregate(
    a=Sum(
        Case(When(a__lt=5, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    b=Sum(
        Case(When(a__lt=10, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm using django 2.0.3, `Count` with `filter` are working in general, but if I use field from annotation in the filter of `Count` then it throws an error. Same with `Sum(When)`.

Comment: The unknown column error? Please update your question to share your actual model and queryset, so we can reproduce your issue.